# How do I do McNemar test for propensity matched data in R?

Tags: propensity-scores, mcnemar-test

I did propensity score matching for retrospective data, and now I want to run outcome analysis. For dichotomous variables, I heard that I need to do McNemar test since I should treat propensity score matched data as paired ones.
Typical t-test table for dichotomous variables would be like:

|  | Treatment group | Control group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | number | number |
| No | number | number |

However, for McNemar test, I figured out that I need another vesion of table like:

|  | Treatment group Yes | No |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Control group Yes | number | number |
| No | number | number |

But I can't figure out how to find those numbers in table above.
Because there are a lot of outcome variables, and number of participants in each group, I cannot count each pair as well.
Please tell me how I can make a table needed and run McNemar's test in R.

Answer (score 0):

McNemar's test isn't the only way to test the association between treatment and a binary outcome in matched data. You can simply run a logistic regression of the outcome on treatment and use a cluster-robust standard error that accounts for the paired nature of the data. This procedure is recommended by [Abadie and Spiess (2022)](https://doi.org/10.1080/01621459.2020.1840383) who prove that it is valid. This is explained in `MatchIt`'s [estimating effects vignette](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/estimating-effects.html). There are a number of benefits to using a regression framework: you can include covariates in the model, you can compute a specific quantity rather than just a p-value, and you can compute a confidence interval around that quantity.