# How do I pair matched data after propensity score matching?

Tags: propensity-scores

I used matchit package for propensity score matching. I got another column under names of  "distance", "weights" and "subclass". What I understood is "subclass" is numbering of each pair after propensity score matching.
I plan to run paired tests such as McNemar test, so I want to pair each row of data according to "subclass".
How can I do this? Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I mentioned in my [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/618608/116195) to your other question, Mcnemar's test is not the bets way to test the hypotheses about an association between treatment and an outcome after matching. I my answer, I provided a link to a vignette that explains exactly how to estimate an effect that uses pair membership to produce a valid p-value for the test of such an association. Was there something inadequate about that answer? Did you read it and the linked vignette?

Comment: Yes, I read your kind answer. I did regression analysis for some of my data, but I still want to compare the incidence between two paired groups. That is why I try to run McNemar's test. Thanks again.

Comment: But a regression of the outcome on the treatment does compare the incidence between the two paired groups (correctly adjusting for the pairing using a cluster-robust SE). There is no reason to a McNemar's test. The exact hypothesis you want to test is correctly tested using the methods in the vignette.